# How to setup a cronjob for Rails on AWS Opsworks using Chef?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I try to setup a cronjob for my Rails app on AWS Opsworks, but I am not sure how it works. There is the official documentation by AWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html

```
cron "job_name" do
  hour "1"
  minute "10"
  weekday "6"
  command "cd /srv/www/myapp/current && rake task"
end
```

But I cannot figure out how it works exactly. Where do I put the code above? Is it a file in my rails app? And how do I trigger this code? With a custom cookbook?

Comment: Why don't you try using **[whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)** gem?

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. But as I understood it, I still have to trigger whenever jobs from at least one cronjob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments whenever gem updates your crontab after each deploy of your application. If you use it, code that goes to crontab is part of your application codebase. This approach is great if your cron job is running task closely relate to your application, such some rake tasks or something like that.

Example that you have found on Amazon docs, is how to update crontab from your chef cookbook. So that code goes to your recipe, and when you run it chef will populate crontab for you. More info about Chef's cron resource you can [find here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html).

Comment: Thanks. So that means I do not need to to trigger the whenever jobs via cron? Instead they add cronjobs on the instance crontab and run automatically  on the instance is deployed? What if I have two parallel instances?

Comment: Yeah whenever just populates crontab for you. You can set on which roles you want to set/use cron jobs, same as you do on Capistrano, check it's GitHub repo for an examples https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Great thanks. But I need to be careful, when I have multiple instance with a load balancer? Because then I have the same cronjobs on each instance?

Comment: Yeah, probably you need to create some roles to determine which ones need cron jobs, or to have some dedicated workers for this kind of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cron layer that only handles running my cron jobs. It's a custom layer, and then I just added all of the rails specific jobs. as seen in this pic.

custom layer with rails for cron that runs rake tasks:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/za3lkiuk8zayzs5/Screenshot%202015-03-01%2022.22.06.png?dl=0

The kit-chef::cronjob is where I have all of my chef cronjobs defined. When ever I add a new cronjob to this recipe I just update_custom_cookbooks on this layer and deploy.

It's always good to do a sanity check and ssh into the cron server and crontab -l as sudo and make sure your new tasks were added. Obviously the custom chef recipes in the pic won't be exactly what you need for your environment.